# Could not install the Python driver for RethinkDB

Tags: python, pip, rethinkdb

Python version: 3.7.3

Pip version: 19.1.1

I am trying to install  the Python driver for RethinkDB but it is failed.

```
pip install rethink
```

It sent me the error notification, that is,

```
"ERROR:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rethink (from version: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rethink"
```

Please help me to solve that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pip install rethinkdb`

Mory info here: https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/guide/python/